# Signature verification fails

Tags: security, digital-signature, x509certificate

Hi I am not able to verify signature for the response that I receive from server. I am using the following method to verify it.

```
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Response.xml")))
  {
    XmlDocument responseDocument = new XmlDocument();
    responseDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    responseDocument.Load(ms);

    SignedXml sxml = new SignedXml(responseDocument);
    XmlNodeList newNodeList = newDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
    sxml.LoadXml((XmlElement)newNodeList[0]);

    sxml.CheckSignature();        

  }
```

Can anyone suggest what can be possible issues? And how to resolve it?
Code is in c#.net

Comment: The problem was related to the signature generation judging by the accepted answer: this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was from signature generation process. It is resolved now.
Above method is correct to verify the signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be wrong. Your code iterates through all Signature tags (fine) **and tries to look for a signature tag inside each signature tag (strange?!)**

Try this code instead:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\Response.xml")))
  {
    XmlDocument responseDocument = new XmlDocument();
    responseDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    responseDocument.Load(ms);
    SignedXml sx = new SignedXml((XmlElement)responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Response")[0]);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
    foreach (XmlElement element in nodeList)
    {
        // Load the signature node.
        sx.LoadXml(element);
        sx.CheckSignature();
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is in case if there are multiple signatures. this is standard code

Comment: What happens, if you pass the complete XmlDocument to the SignedXml constructor? `SignedXml sx = new SignedXml(responseDocument);` instead of `SignedXml sx = new SignedXml((XmlElement)responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Response")[0]);`

Comment: Or just load the XmlDocument directly from the file, without the MemoryStream inbetween.

Comment: in that case if i write responseDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false; it says melformed reference element and if i write responseDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true ; it returns false again.

Comment: Maybe you can upload your file somewhere?

Comment: sorry, that won't be possible.

Comment: Issue was from signature generation process. It is resolved now